# Changing decimal places of X,Y coordinates using proj.4?

Tags: proj

How do I change the accuracy of the output coordinates X,Y in the Proj.4 library (version 4.9)?

In accordance with the manual I tried:

```
proj +proj=poly -f '%.4f' +R=1
```

However, for lat=lon=50, the results

```
'.4f'   '.4f'
```

indicate that the format has not been recognized (OS: Win10).

Comment: Works for me: `echo "50 50" |proj +proj=poly -f '%.4f' +R=1` prints out "0.5201 1.0533" (linux command line)

Comment: @  Spacedman: Are you working under GNU/Linux?

Comment: Yes, does Windows command line treat % as a special character? So proj never sees it?

Comment: Try two %% signs instead of one... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509652/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-a-cmd-file seems to think you need one on the command line and two in a batch file.

Comment: @ Spacedman: Thank you very much for your advice and explanation, it works well!

Comment: @Spacedman please turn your comment into an answer, since it might be helpful to many people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows' command line uses the % sign as a special character for various things. In batch scripts, you need two % signs to signify what you want is actually a % sign. So a .BAT file running proj commands would look like this:

```
proj +proj=poly -f '%%.4f' +R=1
```

For more, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509652/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-a-cmd-file or a Windows command reference. Note you can use the Windows Linux subsystem or Cygwin to get a "bash" shell instead of the Windows command line interpreter.